# When submitting MVC 5 view, data from partial view is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

This question has been asked but none could solve my problem.
The problem is missing or null data from the partial view is not submittied (POST) along with the main view data.

I have a typed partial view called **_Address.cshtml** that I include in another view called Site.cshtml.

The typed site view binds to a view model called **SiteEditModel.cs**

```
public class SiteEditModel
{
   ...properties

   public AddressEditModel Address {get;set;}

  public SiteEditModel()
  {
   Address = new AddressEditModel();
  }
}
```

The **Site view** has a form:

```
        @model Insight.Pos.Web.Models.SiteEditModel
        ...

        @using ( Html.BeginForm( "Edit", "Site", FormMethod.Post ) )
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.SiteId )

            ...

            @Html.Partial( "~/Views/Shared/Address.cshtml", this.Model.Address )

            ...

            @Html.SaveChangesButton()
        }
```

The partial **Address view** is just a bunch of @Html... calls that bind to the Address model.

```
@model Insight.Pos.Web.Models.AddressEditModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
@Html.HiddenFor(...)
@Html.HiddenFor(...)
@Html.HiddenFor(...)
@hmtl.LabelFor(...)
</div>
```

**In the controller action Edit I can see the SiteEditModel is populated correctly, the Address property of that model is not.
Where do I go wrong?**

Thank you so much.

Comment: _Address.cshtml or Address.cshtml?

Answer (score 2):

http://davybrion.com/blog/2011/01/prefixing-input-elements-of-partial-views-with-asp-net-mvc/

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Address.cshtml", Model.Address, new ViewDataDictionary
{
    TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Address" }
})
```

Comment: simpler notation @Daniel Stackenland

Answer (score 1):

The key to fix this is with naming of the partialviews input-elements. The Render partial dont know it's a part of something bigger.

I've make an simple example on how you can fix this in a way that you can have multiple Addresses using the same partial view:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PartialWithPrefix(this HtmlHelper html, string partialViewName, object model, string prefix)
        {
            var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(html.ViewData)
            {
                TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo
                {
                    HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix
                }
            };

            return html.Partial(partialViewName, model, viewData);
        }
    }
```

And use this extensions in the view like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Site", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SiteId)

    @Html.PartialWithPrefix("_Adress", this.Model.Address, "Address")
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

You can of course make this a bit more fancy with expressions and reflection but that's another question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `SiteEditModel` `Address` property is not marked as `public`, change it to this instead:

```
public AddressEditModel Address {get;set;}
```

I would also change your partial to use `SiteEditModel` instead:

```
@model Insight.Pos.Web.Models.SiteEditModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address.FooProperty)

...

</div>
```

This would mean that your properties would end up being named correctly in order for the model binder to pick them up.
Using the above example it would be `Name"=Address.FooProperty"`.

Comment: Thanks. The Address property is already public. That wasn't it. I corrected that in my question. As for using the SiteEditModel in the partial view-- doesn't this beat the goal of having a partial view there? There are other "main" views that also use the _Address partial view, so I suppose I can't pass in the "main view" EditModel?

Comment: @John Your partial will be the same, just the `model` reference will change to enable the model binder naming.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember correctly, the problem is that `Html.Partial` doesn't populate inputs names correctly. You should have something like:

```
<input id="Address.Street" name="Address.Street" />
```

but I assume you have following HTML:

```
<input id="Street" name="Street" />
```

You have few solutions:

1. Insert input name manually:

   ```
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Street, new { Name = "Address.Street" })
   ```
2. Use `Html.EditorFor()`
3. Override names resolving in `Html.Partial()`

The downside of first solution is that you are hardcoding property name, what isn't ideal. I'd recommend using `Html.EditorFor()` or `Html.DisplayFor()` helpers, cause they populate inputs names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Model binder could not bind child models correctly if you are populating them in partial view. Consider using editor templates instead which is implemented for this reason.

Put your `AddressEditModel.cshtml` file in `\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\` folder and in your main view use like this:

```
@using ( Html.BeginForm( "Edit", "Site", FormMethod.Post ) )
{
    // because model type name same as template name MVC automatically picks our template
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Address)

    // or if names do not match set template name explicitly 
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Address,"NameOfTemplate")
}
```